# How to configure methods as asynchronous from XML configuration without using @Async at method

Tags: spring

I have a situation where i need to write xml based configuration for methods which are declared as @Async in spring.

Is there a way we can configure this through xml file for methods instead of declaring methods with @Async annotation.?

Comment: `<task:annotation-driven />` put `@Async` on the methods which you want to be processed async.

Comment: Actually i am trying to give @Async to the methods from XMlL file.

Comment: You cannot do that at the moment. Well it might be if you use `aop:config` write your own pointcut, write your own subclass of the `AbstractAsyncExecutionAspect` to work not with annotations and configure it like that. Would require a serious amount of work.